# Can not read property of array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node-red

Im fairly new to javascript and im trying to find an object of an array i created by the `configID` property. I used the method `find()` for this.

**JS Code:**

```
var configurationArray = flow.get("configurationArray") || [];
var configurationId = msg.topic.split("/")[1];
var configuration = {
  configID: this.configurationID,
  configurationModules: this.MSGesture.payload
};

if(!configurationArray.find(x => x.configID == this, configurationId)){
  configurationArray.push(this.configuration);
} else {
  //to do
}
```

I am using node-red which gives me `flow` and `msg`.

**The Error i get:**

```
Cannot read property 'configId' of undefined
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Error clearly states value of `x` is undefined, just change  it to `x && x.configId`

Comment: Also check if variable is defined and its length `if (configurationArray && !!configurationArray.length && configurationArray.find(...) )`

Comment: @CodeManiac Your answer also worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could destructure the property and add a default object.

Then take `some` instead of `find`, because you need only the check.

At last, omit `this` and take directly the value.

```
if (!configurationArray.some(({ configID } = {}) => configID === configurationId)) {
    configurationArray.push(this.configuration);
} else {
    //to do
}
```

If you like to have an abstract callback, you could take a closure over `configurationId`, like

```
const hasId = id => ({ configID } = {}) => configID === id;

if (!configurationArray.some(hasId(configurationId)) {
    configurationArray.push(this.configuration);
} else {
    //to do
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Could you please explain what the `({ configID } = {})` does? I dont completely understand what it does infront of the `=>`.

Comment: it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). it takes an object, or if the value is `undefined`, then the default object and pulls out `configID` from the object